# i have 2 tables customer and order and find customer id which have maximum order

Tags: sql-server

```
tbi_Customer             tbl_order
CustId int               orderid int
Customer no              OrderName varchar(50)
                         CustId int
```

Comment: Can you please also tell us what have you tried so far to solve the problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by maximum order?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select top 1 a.customerno,b.totalorder from tbl_Customer as a
join (select custid,count(custid) as totalorder from tbl_order group by custid) b on a.custid=b.custid 
order by b.totalorder desc
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no OrderAmount type column, I am assuming what you need is maximum number of orders.

```
select top 1 
 C.[Customer Number], 
 count(C.[Customer Number]) as [Number of Orders] 
from tbl_Customer C join tbl_order O
    on C.CustId = O.CustId 
group by C.[Customer Number] 
order by 2 desc
```